# Show an alert when hover on elements

Tags: javascript

I want to show an alert with the number of divs which don't have the atributte class wrapper when I hover on the divs which have the class wrapper atributte. This seems easy but I just can't see what I did wrong.
This is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="wrapper"> <p> aa </p> </div>
<div class ="wrapper"> <p> dd </p> </div>
<div class ="wrapper"> <p> cc </p> </div>
<div> <p> bb </p> </div> 
<div> <p> bb </p> </div> 
<div> <p> bb </p> </div> 
</body>
<script type ="text/javascript">
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
var ps =document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i=0; i<divs.length; i++){
divs[i].onhover =function(){
var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
alert(ps.length - divs.length)},5000);
setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(intervalId);},25000);
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `onmouseover` instead.

Comment: No, don't.  Use a mouseover eventListener as @user2181397 suggests

Comment: I tried it because it seemed simple to format, but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName` to get total number of `div` and 
`document.getElementsByClassName` to get div with class wrapper

Then use `addEventListener` to add `mouseover` event to this `div`

```
var getTotoalDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper');
var divWithoutWrapper = (getTotoalDiv.length - divs.length);

// Converting nodelist to array since `divs` is a HTMLCollection
var getNodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);
getNodesArray.forEach(function(item) { //using array#forEach method to loop 
  item.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    alert(divWithoutWrapper)
  })
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/etofd5c7/1/)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I tried this method and it doesn't work that good. It starts showing the alert box even when I'm not placed on a div with wrapper class and when I just move my cursor around.

Comment: that is because the div occupy the full width

Comment: Oh , now I understand . Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try tis code 

<script type ="text/javascript">
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
    if(divs[i].getAttribute('class') != 'wrapper'){
        divs[i].addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
            alert('class'); 
        })
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do . But I don't know why , it still doesn't work .

Comment: Hello dear it working,first i was test then post 
If you have any demo link the please provide me. I willl try my best

Comment: Hey , sorry . I replied to your code before I knew something. It's ok . Thank you !